# Why feature selection and extraction help classification?

Tags: classification, svm, feature-selection

We know that svm considers a weight for every dimension of input (vector w), so why we use feature selection or extraction and reduce the dimensions? Isn't it right that if a feature is not important, its w in svm is so low or near to zero?

Comment: They do not help.

Comment: @FrankHarrell hmm, what's the point of using them?

Comment: Parsimony is the enemy of predictive discrimination.  Parsimony is used for its own sake to make things (falsely) appear simpler.  It is not used to improve predictions.